# MVC bizstrap theme responsive slider not displaying

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have taken the template provided by bizstrap and simply listed their Index Page as my Views/Home/Index page.  I then placed the CSS files/JS files into their respective bundles and placed those bundles on the _Layout.cshtml page. The page will display; however, the arrows to scroll, the circles along the bottom of the image and the image transitions themselves is not functioning correctly.  I know this has to do with MVC and me, because I took this exact same thing and placed into my Dreamweaver and it displays perfectly.

I'm not sure what would be helpful to post.

Here is my BundleConfig:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace Victory
{
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-{version}.js"));



        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/biz_rs_css").Include(
            "~/Content/biz_css/rs-plugin/css/settings.css",
            "~/Content/biz_css/rs-responsive.css"));
       bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/biz_css/custom.css"));  
   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bizfile_css1").Include(
            "~/Content/biz_css/styler.css",
            "~/Content/biz_css/isotope.css",
            "~/Content/biz_css/color_scheme.css"
            ));
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bizfile_css2").Include(
       "~/Content/biz_css/font-awesome.css",
       "~/Content/biz_css/font-awesome-ie7.css",
       "~/Content/biz_css/flexslider.css",
       "~/Content/biz_css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bizsitejs").Include(
            "~/Scripts/biz_js/style-switcher.js",
            "~/Scripts/biz_js/style-switcher/jquery.cookie.js",
            "~/Scripts/biz_js/style-switcher/iris.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/biz_js/revolution.custom.js",
            "~/Scripts/biz_js/jquery.fancybox.pack.2.1.0.js",
            "~/Scripts/biz_js/jquery.isotope.js",
            "~/Scripts/biz_js/jquery.flexslider-min.js",
            "~/Scripts/biz_js/jquery.countdown.js",
            "~/Scripts/biz_js/custom.js",
            "~/Scripts/biz_js/countdown_script.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bizsiters").Include(
            "~/Scripts/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"));


        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));


         BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

    }
}
```

}

My _Layout page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>



    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <!--  SEO STUFF START HERE -->
    <title>bizstrap Premium Corporate HTML Template Home</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="robots" content="follow, index" />
    <!--  SEO STUFF END -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="~/Scripts/biz_js/style-switcher.js"></script>
    <!--  revolution slider plugin : begin -->
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/biz_rs_css")
    <!--  revolution slider plugin : end -->
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bizfile_css1")      <linkhref="http://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Open+Sans:400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bizfile_css2")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <link href="~/Scripts/biz_js/style-switcher/styler.css" rel="stylesheet"  />
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/IE-fix.css" />
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
@RenderBody()
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap",
           "~/bundles/bizsitejs", "~/bundles/bizsiters");
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
   </body>
    </html>
```

I feel like this is something to do with the timing of loading the files.  Again in Dreamweaver, this theme displays without even a problem.  I've spent a large amount of time building the MVC for this program (databases, email, etc) all the functions work, but I can't get this to display correctly.

ANY help is greatly appreciated.